# Step extraction from a paragraph

Tags: machine-learning, data-science-model, nlp

Came across an interesting problem:

Given a paragraph describing how to do a process, need to break it down to various steps. Basically, need to determine for each sentence in the paragraph, if this is start of a new step or belongs to the previous step.

The paragraph here describes a particular process.

Example: How to install a software. So the first step in this case can be the system requirements. All the sentences regarding this need to be in the same step. The sentences thereafter stating how to download this would belong to the next step. The sentences thereafter stating how to install this would belong to the next step.

This is just breaking the paragraph into meaningful steps.

Any idea how to go about this, what algorithm/model to use?